# Network connection degrades after a while

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

My topology is as follows:

```
Fiber -> Modem --[PPPoE]--> WiFi Router --[Cable]--> Win Computer A
                                  |
                                  `-------[Cable]--> Mac Computer B
```

My WiFi Router is an RT-AC66R and it has the latest official firmware. I have changed the network cables and the router ports while debugging this issue, but nothing changed.

The IPs are 192.168.1.217 (A) and 192.168.1.164 (B).

Right after I turn the Windows Computer on the ping times from the Mac computer are within a few milliseconds. After a while, it starts degrading:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.1.217: icmp_seq=1277 ttl=128 time=4617.294 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.217: icmp_seq=1278 ttl=128 time=3614.986 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.217: icmp_seq=1279 ttl=128 time=8025.265 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.217: icmp_seq=1280 ttl=128 time=8024.973 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.217 ping statistics ---
1289 packets transmitted, 1021 packets received, 20.8% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.313/4254.498/9027.763/2814.197 ms
```

When finally I get 100% packet loss:

```
mbp13:~ $ ping 192.168.1.217
PING 192.168.1.217 (192.168.1.217): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
^C
--- 192.168.1.217 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

And the same is true from the B computer to the A:

```
C:\Windows\System32>ping 192.168.1.164

Pinging 192.168.1.164 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.217: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.217: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.217: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.217: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.164:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

One thing that I think that contributes to this problem is that I am using a VPN program on the Windows Computer from AT&T. Here's the complete network interface list for the Windows Computer:

```
C:\Windows\System32>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ADMINIB-UMUK56L
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : br.ibm.com
                                       br.ibm.com
                                       ibm.com
                                       br.ibm.com
                                       ibm.com
                                       br.ibm.com
                                       ibm.com
                                       br.ibm.com
                                       ibm.com
                                       br.ibm.com
                                       ibm.com

Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network) #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0C-84-DC-E7-EF-3E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : br.ibm.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : AGN Virtual Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 02-50-F2-00-00-05
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e927:5878:a84b:6a93%16(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 9.18.197.97(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 9.78.134.254(Duplicate)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 654463218
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-7B-08-38-28-D2-44-48-BC-D6
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 9.0.132.50
                                       9.0.134.50
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : A4-4E-31-EC-A2-F8
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 28-D2-44-48-BC-D6
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::65db:7ae2:5eb0:df7c%12(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.217(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, May 15, 2015 1:48:09 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, May 16, 2015 1:48:09 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 352330188
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-7B-08-38-28-D2-44-48-BC-D6
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5cf2:8c43:c13:2c00:3f57:fe26(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c13:2c00:3f57:fe26%10(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{41161D7E-20EC-4444-A6DC-18861FEACA07}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.br.ibm.com:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : br.ibm.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{3ACCE85C-CBDA-4533-B4C5-BDCD00EEB1AD}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{5536D00D-DF99-4540-BAB6-B0A790A70A81}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter 6TO4 Adapter:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : br.ibm.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft 6to4 Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:912:c561::912:c561(Preferred)
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2002:94e:86fe::94e:86fe(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 9.0.132.50
                                       9.0.134.50
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with modem or router. As those PCs are on the same ethernet segment, traffic goes directly. All these routers have internal switch between those 4 LAN ports and traffic among them does not go through the firmware or CPU of the router.

Comment: If you are able to, you can try to use `Wireshark` on one of the PCs to see what packets are going through the wire during the pings (retransmits, sent packets without any response, ARP requests, ...).